# Associating tables in a sport database. Fixture list - home club and away club

Tags: php, mysql

How to display instead of clubI homeD and club questID, display the home clubName and quest clubName. It now works correctly displays the correct club ID, but how to display the name ClubName instead.  **Tables in my database:**

```
clubs (clubID, clubName)
matches (matchesID, homeID, questID, homeGoals, questGoals)





    <?php
$result = $conn->prepare(
"SELECT 
 m.matchesID
 hc.clubName as homeClub, 
 gc.clubName as guestClub, 
 m.homeGoals, 
 m.guestGoals
FROM matches AS m
JOIN clubs AS hc ON hc.clubID = m.homeID
JOIN clubs AS gc ON gc.clubID = m.guestID ORDER BY matchesID ASC");

$result->execute();
$results = $result->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $index => $row){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['matchID']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['homeClub']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['guestClub']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['homeGoals']; ?> : <?php echo $row['guestGoals']; ?></label></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is a quest like a guest?

Comment: How to display instead of clubI homeD and club questID, display the home clubName and quest clubName

Comment: Is a quest a bit like a guest? Is this a question or a guestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm a reading your question correctly then this might work

```
$result = $conn->prepare(
"SELECT 
 m.matchesID
 hc.clubName as homeClub, 
 gc.clubName as guestClub, 
 m.homeGoals, 
 m.guestGoals
FROM matches AS m
JOIN clubs AS hc ON hc.clubID = m.homeID
JOIN clubs AS gc ON gc.clubID = m.guestID ORDER BY matchesID ASC");

$result->execute();
$results = $result->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $index => $row){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['matchesID']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['homeClub']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['guestClub']; ?></label></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['homeGoals']; ?> : <?php echo $row['guestGoals']; ?></label></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I checked the names everything agrees from where this error occurred::  Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.clubName as homeClub, gc.clubName as guestClub ' at line 1

Comment: Try changing from ORDER BY matchID to ORDER BY matchesID

Comment: I corrected the code at the top. I corrected the "matches" immediately. I checked the names with the base, they agree, because the clubID was displayed correctly. The error must be SELECT.      ...syntax to use near '.clubName as homeClub, gc.clubName as guestClub, m.homeGoals, m.guestGo' at line 3

Comment: Did you change from guestGoals to questGoals as well?

Comment: Yes, you were right + one comma was missing. Thank you very much.